# Chaining Promises correctly

Tags: javascript, typescript, sharepoint, promise

I want to create a list if it doesn't exist and then create the fields, aka ensure.  I'm having trouble understanding how to set the promises:

```
public getLocations(): Promise<ILocations[]> {
    let promise: Promise<ILocations[]> = new Promise<ILocations[]>((resolve, reject): void => {
        sp.web.lists.ensure("DeliveryBoardLocations")
            .then((ler: ListEnsureResult): Promise<ListEnsureResult> => {
                console.log("got list ensure result");

                if (ler.created) {
                    console.log("Locations was created");

                    let batch = sp.web.createBatch();

                    ler.list.fields.inBatch(batch).addText("textField");
                    ler.list.fields.inBatch(batch).addDateTime("dateField");
                    ler.list.fields.inBatch(batch).addBoolean("booleanField");

                    batch.execute()
                        .then((): Promise<ListEnsureResult> => {
                            console.log("fields created");

                            let batch = sp.web.createBatch();
                            let view = ler.list.defaultView;

                            view.fields.inBatch(batch).add("textField");
                            view.fields.inBatch(batch).add("dateField");
                            view.fields.inBatch(batch).add("booleanField");

                            batch.execute()
                                .then((): Promise<ListEnsureResult> => {
                                    console.log("fields added to view; returning ler");

                                    return ler;
                                });
                        });

                    // return;
                }
                else {
                    console.log("Locations already existed; returning ler");

                    resolve(ler.list);
                    return Promise.reject("List Exists");
                }

                console.log("after if stmt");
            })
            .then((ler): void => {
                console.log("ler: ", ler);
                console.log("ler.list: ", ler.list);
                console.log("ler.list.items: ", ler.list.items);

                resolve(ler.list.items.getAll());
            });
    });

    return promise;
}
```

Console shows:

```
LocationsService.ts:16 got list ensure result
LocationsService.ts:19 Locations was created
LocationsService.ts:56 after if stmt
LocationsService.ts:59 ler:  undefined
LocationsService.ts:31 fields created
LocationsService.ts:43 fields added to view; returning ler
```

I want to call ensure; if result comes back that the list was created then create the columns and display them.  Then return the list so I can get all the items and return the items.  If the list is created, return the items.

I'm having trouble figuring out how this should be handled.

Comment: This seems to be a bit complex for just creating/updating a list. Ensure is a a kind of finally but still in the chain. Easier would be a Promise.all() and just show a meaningful error if it rejects. Or just get the data (with a promise) and 'then' build the list, no async/promise logic needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essential failing of the code is missing returns, which, in the case of promise chains, convey data *and* control flow.

You can also purge the `new Promise()` wrapper. The chain starting `sp.web.lists.ensure()` is perfectly adequate without the wrapper.

You also need to address the type casting clauses. `Promise<ListEnsureResult>` is probably not correct in all cases. Try `<any>` to get yourself started.

```
public getLocations(): Promise<ILocations[]> {
    // let promise: Promise<ILocations[]> = new Promise<ILocations[]>((resolve, reject): void => { // not necessary
        return sp.web.lists.ensure('DeliveryBoardLocations')
        ^^^^^^
        .then((ler: ListEnsureResult): Promise<ListEnsureResult> => { // <any> ?
            if (ler.created) {
                let batch = sp.web.createBatch();
                ler.list.fields.inBatch(batch).addText('textField');
                ler.list.fields.inBatch(batch).addDateTime('dateField');
                ler.list.fields.inBatch(batch).addBoolean('booleanField');
                return batch.execute()
                ^^^^^^
                .then((): Promise<ListEnsureResult> => { // <any> ?
                    let batch = sp.web.createBatch();
                    let view = ler.list.defaultView;
                    view.fields.inBatch(batch).add('textField');
                    view.fields.inBatch(batch).add('dateField');
                    view.fields.inBatch(batch).add('booleanField');
                    return batch.execute()
                    ^^^^^^
                    .then((): Promise<ListEnsureResult> => ler); // <any> ?
                });
            }
            else {
                // resolve(ler.list); // not necessary 
                // return Promise.reject('List Exists'); // eek, confounding after resolve.
                throw new Error('List Exists'); // it's more economical to throw rather than return Promise.reject(...). Also, be sure to throw an Error() object. 
            }
        })
        .then((ler): void => {
            // resolve(ler.list.items.getAll()); // not necessary
            return ler.list.items.getAll();
        });
    // });
    // return promise;
}
```

In practice, you might choose to simplify slightly by rearranging (and cleaning up):

```
public getLocations(): Promise<ILocations[]> {
    return sp.web.lists.ensure('DeliveryBoardLocations')
    .then((ler: ListEnsureResult): Promise<any> => {
        if (ler.created) {
            let batch = sp.web.createBatch();
            ler.list.fields.inBatch(batch).addText('textField');
            ler.list.fields.inBatch(batch).addDateTime('dateField');
            ler.list.fields.inBatch(batch).addBoolean('booleanField');
            return batch.execute()
            .then((): Promise<any> => {
                let batch = sp.web.createBatch();
                let view = ler.list.defaultView;
                view.fields.inBatch(batch).add('textField');
                view.fields.inBatch(batch).add('dateField');
                view.fields.inBatch(batch).add('booleanField');
                return batch.execute();
            })
            .then(() => ler.list.items.getAll()); // rearranged
        } else {
            throw new Error('List Exists');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually return the `batch` promises, otherwise the outer-wrapping promise just immediately finishes executing instead of waiting for them and giving the result.

```
return batch.execute()
    .then((): Promise<ListEnsureResult> => {
        console.log("fields created");

        let batch = sp.web.createBatch();
        let view = ler.list.defaultView;

        view.fields.inBatch(batch).add("textField");
        view.fields.inBatch(batch).add("dateField");
        view.fields.inBatch(batch).add("booleanField");

        return batch.execute()
            .then((): Promise<ListEnsureResult> => {
                console.log("fields added to view; returning ler");

                return ler;
            });
    });
```

Comment: Ok, I implemented your solution but the "return ler" is giving me a error: 
`[16:45:44] Error - [tsc] src/Services/LocationsService.ts(98,37): error TS2322: Type 'ListEnsureResult' is not assignable to type 'Promise<ListEnsureResult>'.`

Comment: Remove `: Promise<ListEnsureResult>` from the block causing the issue. Promises are allowed to return either the concrete type *or* a Promise-wrapped version of the type.

Comment: Ok, I removed both promises, it logs "fields created" but doesn't get to "fields added to view" comment.